# Image Data Generator Keras out of data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
train_datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.1,
        zoom_range=0.1,
        horizontal_flip=False,
        width_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images horizontally (fraction of total width)
        height_shift_range=0.1)  # randomly shift images vertically (fraction of total height))

test_datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255) 

train_it = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(r"...", batch_size=16, target_size=(224, 224), shuffle = True, class_mode='categorical')
test_it = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(r"...", batch_size=16, target_size=(224, 224), shuffle = True, class_mode='categorical')

trans = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(224,224,3), include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
trans.trainable = False

modell = tf.keras.Sequential([
    trans,
    layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
    layers.Dropout(0.5),
    layers.Dense(2),
    layers.Activation("softmax")
])
modell.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["acc"])

modell.fit_generator(
            train_it,
            steps_per_epoch=2000,
            epochs=50,
            verbose=1,
            validation_data=test_it,
            validation_steps=50)
```

The training works fine when I set `steps_per_epoch` to 200 and the `validation_steps` to 10. But any higher number (e.g. 50) yields this error:

`WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least steps_per_epoch * epochs batches (in this case, 50 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.`

To my knowledge, since I'm using DataAugmentation here, it shouldn't be possible at all that the generator runs out of data.

What's wrong here? Might that be connected to the MobileNet?

Comment: The error is quite self-explanatory. Your generator needs to be able to generate **at least** `steps_per_epoch` batches. For example say you have 1000 datapoints and a batch size of 100. Then `steps_per_epoch=10` is fine, but `steps_per_epoch=50` will raise an error (because there are not that many batches in the dataset). The augmentation applies augmentation to that batch afaik. So that doesn't help.